# How can I crop everything outside of an art board in Sketch 4?

Tags: sketch-app

I need to cut my layers to be only inside the artboard, these 2 images will show you what I mean:

[image]

To be like:

[image]

So the layer that has some of it outside the screen got cut off. What is the way or plugin to do this?

Comment: I don't personally know a way or plugin, but I'm wondering why you would even need to do that?

Comment: Agree with Jane.  If it's outside the artboard, it's essentially cropped already.  Why delete and lost that part of the image, when you can keep it?

Comment: Totally disagree. Imagine a large svg file like a detailed map. That'd be a TON of shapes adding to file size and slowing down Sketch.

Comment: @Jay There is really no reason for a (competent) software to process things outside the bounding window so it does not really impact anything other than file operations and memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cut the layer but you can [mask](https://sketchapp.com/docs/shapes/masking/) the layer to get minimize the size of the layer and get control while designing.

Follow these steps to mask your layer using invisible / transparent rectangle shape.

**Step 1:**

You have your layer (Combined shape in the given example) which is partially outside the artboard.

[image]

**Step 2:**

Create a transparent rectangle shape in behind your layer. Remove fill and border to make it transparent. Make sure the rectangle is inside your artboard and covers the part of the layer inside artboard.

[image]

**Step 3:**

Select transparent rectangle and your layer. Select **Layer -> Mask -> Use as Mask** to mask the layer with rectangle shape.

[image]